# no partitions when insalling ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to create a dual boot for ubuntu, with windows 10 already installed. I am in the install ubuntu installation type step.
Here is what it looks like
[image]
If I click install now for /dev/sda here is what I get[image]

So I tried looking at Gparted.
This is what I get
[image]
Now if I clicked *Cancel* I get this:
[image]
If I clicked *Ignore* I get this:
[image]

Also I used boot-repair. I have a pastebin output from it. If that would be helpful I will put that link as well.
What should I do?

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information about this site is available in the [help]. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have not created partition in the disk which is done by right clicking on windows drive in which you want to install. You can refer to this you tube link for proper steps  https://youtu.be/4jGQl6SeS2o You tube link.